# Vaadin calendar month style

Tags: calendar, styles, vaadin

Is there any way to customize Vaadin calendar's month style?
It's default is 1 Dec and i want to make Dec to bold. 1 **Dec**

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the default style

```
.v-calendar-header-month {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I have not tested that style, so I am not sure if is what you are looking for, however is a good aproach.

More info [here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/calendar.appearance.html).